# Error occurred:There is no active transaction

Tags: php, mysql

before i created this post i searched. but can't find a solution
im really having a hard time so i decided to ask for a help
and the problem is it doesn't give the line number where the error is found, i use ajax to call the php code below. i even go to the url of the file. checked the variable if it has data in it. tried executing the stored procedure on phpmyadmin but it works perfectly so i know that the error is in the php file. when i tried to run it directly the INSERT works. but the UPdate doesn't so what i expected is it will rollback the insert but it didn't and it keep populating my table. thanks. and sorry for my bad english

here is the code

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname",$username, $password, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING));
$temp1 = "LHPL003";
$temp2 = "log013";
$rel = "Released";

$stmt = $conn->prepare("CALL sp_insertdocumentsignatory (?,?, ?)");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $temp1, PDO::PARAM_STR, 30); 
$stmt->bindParam(2, $temp2, PDO::PARAM_STR, 10); 
$stmt->bindParam(3, $rel, PDO::PARAM_STR, 10); 
$stmt->execute(); 
if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname",$username, $password, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING));
        $insert2 = $conn->prepare("CALL    sp_updatedocument (?,?)");
        $insert2->bindParam(1,  $temp1, PDO::PARAM_STR, 30); 
        $insert2->bindParam(2, $temp2, PDO::PARAM_STR, 10); 
        $insert2->execute();
        if($insert2->rowCount() > 0) {
        $conn->commit();
        } else {
        $conn->rollBack();
        }
}else {
    $conn->rollBack();
}
```

Comment: You never started a transaction with `$conn->beginTransaction()`. Did you want a transaction wrapped around both the insert and update? If so, you need to explicitly start it beforehand.

Comment: Also, you are reconnecting `$conn` on for the update. That should not happen, as your connection to the database is the same and reusable. Do not call `new PDO()` inside the `if ()` block

Comment: can you show me example code sir? i changed my code but the UPdate doesn't work. but it didn't show me error

Comment: Please edit above to show what your current code is. Also, explain how you want the transaction to work. Should the transaction encompass both the `sp_insertdocumentsignatory` and `sp_updatedocument` procedures, and rollback _both_ if either fails?